# cortana doesn't play groove

Tags: windows, cortana

I have Windows 10 italian language. When I ask Cortana to play an artist she opens Groove Music, but she prompts a message: "Impossibile trovare elementi sull'altro lato del colegamento".
When I write the same research in Groove Music search box, it finds many songs and albums.
What is the problem? Is there possible to use this feature in Italian Language?

Comment: Do you only have that problem when you want to play music or every time you use Cortana?

Comment: I have the problem only when I ask Cortana for an album or a singer. When I ask to play a single song, she finds it and she plays correctly. The singers are correctly categorized by Groove